# Reference for unbounded operators

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory

I've run into some unbounded operators in my research and need to learn some of the theory of unbounded operators. Particularly I want a rigorous treatment that discusses symmetric operators, self-adjoint operators, positive operators, etc. I'd also like a discussion of the spectral theorem and square roots of operators as well if possible. I've looked at some texts but none really jumped out at me. Are there any standard texts which are fairly thorough and cover a lot of the above?

Comment: The book from where I learned these things was Kosaku Yosida's Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators.

Comment: http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466221.html  and  http://store.doverpublications.com/0486453316.html

Comment: @WillJagy I was looking at these two in particular. They seemed promising. Thanks.

Comment: @Pp.. I downloaded the text. I'll have a look at it. It seems to have plenty of examples in mind so it might be a good reference for such things. Thanks

Comment: newer refs for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Symmetric_operators_and_self-adjoint_operators

Comment: The professor for my operator theory course has some great notes on his website: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~loss/14SPRINGTEA/math7334.html

Comment: @Math1000 Hah. I was actually looking at these notes a couple of days ago. They're pretty good. I was disappointed by the lack of examples but I just noticed the notes on the Laplace operator. This is *exactly* what I needed. I understand the theory just fine but it was a little inobvious as to how to implement it. My research actually parallels Fourier theory a bit so those notes are very, very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to suggest Reed/Simon: Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics 1, chapter VIII. It gives a quite careful treatment and emphasizes connections to e.g. quantum mechanics, where unbounded operators occur very naturally (e.g. because they have arbitrarily high eigenvalues, such as $$-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x$$ defined on Schwartz space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbf{R})$). For the same reason it discusses a lot concerning the spectral theorem for unbounded operators.

Comment: This is the text that I ended up going with. I started reading some of it yesterday. Definitely does what I need. The only problem I have with it is that it doesn't have quite enough examples, but I guess that is where the other texts will come into play.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I think the examples are mostly in the exercises. Also, a great deal of volume 2 discusses very serious examples which are quite hard to prove to be self-adjoint, such as certain Schrödindiger operators. In any case, R/S is a great choice, I learned a lot from this book.